# App showing 404 error when viewed within a FB Page

Tags: facebook, tabs, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to display a hosted form on my business page as a 'Page Tab'.

I have created a new app, entered the URLs into the Page Tab section, saved, and added the app to my page. I have both http and https URLS to satisfy Facebook's requirements.

I have filled in the Basic info and the Page Tab information only, then saved.

But when I add the app to my page and view it in a live environment I see:

> **The page cannot be found**
>
> The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please try the following:
>
> Make sure that the Web site address displayed in the address bar of
>   your browser is spelled and formatted correctly. If you reached this
>   page by clicking a link, contact the Web site administrator to alert
>   them that the link is incorrectly formatted. Click the Back button to
>   try another link. HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
>   Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> Go to Microsoft Product Support Services and perform a title search
>   for the words HTTP and 404. Open IIS Help, which is accessible in IIS
>   Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled Web Site Setup, Common
>   Administrative Tasks, and About Custom Error Messages.*

The URLS are: http://www.mardevdm2.com/reports/eForm.html (and the corresponding https version of the same URL)

The page for the app is: https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=169630223121106

What am I doing wrong?  When embedded in a business page it displays the above 404 error.  But in all other instances the content is visible.

Answer (score 3):

When it's an app on a tab, the request from Facebook is sent as a POST request, is your server set up to allow that?

That error message is generated from your server, so check your own logs and see what the request from Facebook was, it should be pretty easy to see why your server returned 404 once you know exactly what the Facebook request was

Comment: Hi, the form uses method=”post” so I assume this is set-up correctly.  Could it be something else?

Comment: Is your page tab URL set up correctly? that error is from your own server, check the logs and see what page us being requested.